# Is there a way to compute $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 1/(1+n!)$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is there a way to compute the exact value of the following series?
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{1+n!}
\end{equation}

I know that it converges to a number less than $e$, since $e=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 1/n!$. I also know that the approximated value is $1.52607$. But can I express the exact value using known constants or functions, such as $e, \pi, \Gamma$?

Comment: i upvoted - good question.

Comment: I know that $(1/n!) - (1/[1 + n!]) = 1/[n!(1+n!)],$ but that idea doesn't seem to lead anywhere.

Comment: There is no known closed form for this. see [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A217702)

Comment: What about integration.  Again, this is just an idea.  $\frac{D(1/n!)}{dn} = -\frac{n!}{1+n!}.$

Comment: @Vilakshan Your comment begs a question which I (for one) have never heard of an answer to.  How does one go about determining whether a specific (for example) infinite summation has a closed form expression?  Related question: how does one prove (for example) that there is no closed form expression for $\int e^{(x^2)}dx$?

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3832142/is-there-any-known-value-for-sum-n-1-infty-frac11n) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25169/are-there-clever-ways-to-evaluate-this-infinite-series).

Comment: @user2661923 : For integrals, see the [Risch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) and [differential Galois theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_Galois_theory) (as used [here](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/a.debray/lecture_notes/u19_differential_Galois_theory.pdf)).  The situation for sums is more fragmented.  A method for some sums is to show a sum is nonelementary by investigating its [Wilf-Zeilberger pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilf%E2%80%93Zeilberger_pair).  There are other methods (for other forms of sums) in the literature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a reasonable approximation
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{1+n!}\sim\sum_{n=0}^p\frac{1}{1+n!}+\sum_{n=p+1}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}-\sum_{n=p+1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n!)^2}+\cdots$$
$$\sum_{n=p+1}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}=e\left(1-\frac{ \Gamma (p+1,1)}{\Gamma (p+1)}\right)$$
$$\sum_{n=p+1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n!)^2}=I_0(2)-a_p$$ where the $a_p$ make the sequence
$$\left\{0,1,2,\frac{9}{4},\frac{41}{18},\frac{1313}{576},\frac{5471}{2400},\frac{118
   1737}{518400},\frac{28952557}{12700800},\frac{1235309099}{541900800},\frac{15009
   0055529}{65840947200}\right\}$$

Using $p=9$
$$\frac{10373124947763317933}{6797289565413518325}+e-\frac{98641}{36288}+\frac{150090055529}{65840947200}-I_0(2)$$ which gives
$$1.5260681344733308247571$$ while the "exact" value is
$$1.5260681344733308247780$$

Comment: . . . nice! . .